# Where in Laravel locate logic?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create my own client to work with Twitter.

Where it locate in laravel? Create special folder in App folder? Or laravel has place for such code constructions?

Comment: You can place it wherever you want. Laravel doesn't explicity specify directories you have to put code inside. However, I personally use App/Helpers/someclass.php for functions that don't fit neither to controllers nor models. But everything "depends", your question is not enough clear to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't explicitly specify directories you have to put code inside.

You can put code wherever you want.

But, I advice put it in semantically right path. For example, `App/Utils/`.